# por que no funciona el condicional if en php con variables inicializadas correctamente

Tags: php, laravel, condiciones

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web para reservar turnos en un centro de manicure. Tengo una pagina que valida si la fecha y hora escogida para el nuevo turno no se cruza con alguna fecha y hora de otra cita previamente agendada por el usuario. Mi problema radica en que al momento de hacer las validaciones parece ser que ninguna es de las condiciones es `true` y por lo tanto el proceso continua con la el `else` y redirige al usuario a la pagina de confirmación con el resumen del turno. Lo que no entiendo y he estado intentando solucionar es porque no se cumplen las condiciones `if` si al parecer las variables debidamente inicializadas. Estoy utilizando Laravel 7

El turno de ejemplo esta programado para

> Fecha: miércoles 8 julio de 8am a 9am

desde una pagina previa ya se han realizado los ciclos y validaciones correspondientes para mostrar fecha, empleados y horas disponibles. La parte de la validación que menciono en este problema inicia cuando el cliente selecciona una hora, la cual queda asociada a una fecha dada por un ciclo. Todas estas variables las recibo en una funcion index del controlador con la clase `Request` y se asignan respectivamente dentro de la funcion. A continuación relaciono el codigo de dicho controlador. Espero haberme hecho entender. Disculpen lo largo de la consulta.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Service;
use App\Employee;
use App\Booking;

class ConfirmationController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $request->user()->id;
        $services = Service::where('id',$request->service)->get();
        $employees = Employee::where('id',$request->employee)->get();
        $date = $request->date;
        $start = $request->start;
        $duration = $request->duration;
        $end = $start + $duration;
        $category = Service::where('id', $request->service)->first('id_category');

        
        // Antes de mostrar la vista confirmacion se valida si el usuario ya tiene alguna cita para esa misma fecha y hora
        $bookingsOfUser = Booking::where('date', date('Y-m-d', $date))->where('id_user', $user)->get();

        if (isset($bookingsOfUser) && count($bookingsOfUser) > 0) { // Si el usuario tiene citas programadas para esa fecha
            

            foreach ($bookingsOfUser as $bookinguser) {
                $bookinguser = $bookinguser;                
            }

            if ($start == $bookinguser->start) {
              return 'Fallo 1';
            }

            if ($start > $bookinguser->start && $start < $bookinguser->end) {
              return 'Fallo 2';
            }

            if ($start < $bookinguser->start && $end > $bookinguser->start) {
              return 'Fallo 3';
            }

            if ($start < $bookinguser->end && $end > $bookinguser->end) {
              return 'Fallo 4';
            }
            else {
            
              setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_CO.utf8'); // Se establece locale en español

                  $data = [
                    'services' => $services,
                    'employees' => $employees,
                    'date' => $date,
                    'start' => $start,
                  ];

                  return view('confirmation')->with($data);
            }
        }        
        else {
          
            setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_CO.utf8'); // Se establece locale en español

                $data = [
                  'services' => $services,
                  'employees' => $employees,
                  'date' => $date,
                  'start' => $start,
                ];

                return view('confirmation')->with($data);
        }

      
    } //end function index
  } //end class
```

Comment: Esta asignación para que? `$bookinguser = $bookinguser;`

Comment: Ten cuidado con el foreach de `$bookingsOfUser`,  te recomiendo hacerle un `print_r` a `$bookinguser` antes y después de la asignación `$bookinguser = $bookinguser; ` para veas dónde está tu _posible_ error.

Comment: @BetaM la asignación `$bookinguser = $bookinguser;` la hice para cargar los datos que vienen de la bd y usarlos fuera del foreach porque de lo contrario me indicaba que no encontraba las propiedades por ej: `$bokinguser->start` Y lo estaba utilizando fuera del foreach porque no sabia con continuar en caso de que las condiciones if no se cumplieran. Muchas gracias por la pregunta.

Comment: @Deilusia al realizar el `print_r` antes de asignar `$bookinguser` en el foreach me indica `Undefined variable: bookinguser` y al hacerlo después me muestra los datos cargados desde la bd. El resultado lo puedes ver en (https://pastebin.com/gQfgPeuw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta en el bucle del if primero, concretamente en el foreach.
antes del if, has sacado todos los $bookingsOfUser de bbdd. Ahora en tu if compruebas si tienes resultados.
En caso de tener resultados, debes iterar por CADA uno de ellos, para comprobar si alguno tiene agendado esos mismos datos (cumpliendo tus condiciones).

EL problema por tanto esta en el foreach. Abres y cierras en la asignacion. Por esto, solo te coje el ultimo registro que tengas.

```
foreach ($bookingsOfUser as $bookinguser) {
    if ($start == $bookinguser->start) {
          return 'Fallo 1';
    }

    if ($start > $bookinguser->start && $start < $bookinguser->end) {
          return 'Fallo 2';
    }

    if ($start < $bookinguser->start && $end > $bookinguser->start) {
          return 'Fallo 3';
    }

    if ($start < $bookinguser->end && $end > $bookinguser->end) {
          return 'Fallo 4';
    }
}
```

una vez hecho este bucle, si no se ha dado alguna de las condiciones (no has hecho un return) entonces tus datos pueden ser registrados. No necesitarias un else, puesto que sigues en la primera condicion. Asi que despues de este bucle, puedes hacer:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_CO.utf8'); // Se establece locale en español
$data = [
   'services' => $services,
   'employees' => $employees,
   'date' => $date,
   'start' => $start,
 ];

 return view('confirmation')->with($data);
```

Comment: muchas gracias por ayudarme a ahorrar tantos `else` innecesarios. Ya incluí los condicionales if dentro del `foreach`, también elimine el if que estaba por fuera de este y además el `$bookinguser = $bookinguser;` que tampoco era necesario y ya me toma el `return 'Fallo 2';` y `return 'Fallo 3';` Aunque todavía no logro que funcione como espero, por lo menos ya veo una luz. El código quedo así (https://pastebin.com/gNX1gg4s) Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas. Muy útiles.